# Product won't save. Processing forever

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I'm doing a module to Magento my module have the same functions of Crosssell native function from magento.
I have this product grid and the user select some checkboxes to associate this products to the main product.
All ok.

But, I've create a custom attribute to save the ID's of this products and make a Observer to 'catalog_product_save_after' event:

```
  <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <brindeproduto_save_product_data>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>brindeproduto/observer</class>
                    <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                </brindeproduto_save_product_data>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
```

On my saveProductTabData I load the main product by the ID on Request, and put the IDS of the selecte products on my custom attribute like these "1,2,3,4,5,6".

Ok, but when I do $product->save(); I got infinite load on my browser, without any error or exeption. 
The code on observer are simple.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
//some logical Specific information that is not in question now.
$product->save();
```

Nothing more.

I've tryed debug the save function and get some intriguing result.
On Mage_Core_Model_Abstract function save(), I put some die on parts of code, and get all of then. this code it's part of function save line 330 on Magento 1.5 Community.

```
    if ($dataCommited) {
        $this->_afterSaveCommit();
    }
    return $this;
```

It's the last line on function. I put die before return.

```
    if ($dataCommited) {
        $this->_afterSaveCommit();
    }
    die('test');
    return $this;
```

I've got the die. But nothing more before return. Some body have ideia of what's happen?? Lost by 5 hours on that.
Any help will be mutch appreciated.

Comment: I've changed my code to Observer just call a Model to do the save action, and now i got SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'value' cannot be null

Comment: Could you add your observer code? you should no be doing any save in your observer, else you going to get in to a never ending loop

Comment: Lol, you make all sense. @R.S, i even think about that. If i save on observer after save he'll call the same observar again and again. lol maybe this Integrity constraint violation are caused by this problem becouse trying save the product multiple times maybe broke the database, I'm recovering the database now.

Comment: @R.S put your answer on Answers to mark as right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT be doing any save in your observer (*_save_after).

This will cause a never ending loop

Comment: Ty very mutch R.S some times we are blind to obvious problem and need somebody from outside to see. Ty man.